# Sublime/Git is adding and removing blank lines in commits

Tags: git, commit, sublimetext2

When I edit a single line in a file either sublime or git adds then removes many of the other (mostly blank) lines in the file.

Here is an example of this

```
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
module UserHelper
-  
+
   def create_test_users
-    
+
```

It is just obfuscating the actual changes I am making, which makes code reviews especially difficult.

Also, both the original file and my editor are using unix line endings.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here--if you try editing files with other extensions (assuming you're using extensions on your files) does this problem occur?

Comment: It was a sublime problem, in the configuration I removed 
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
This seems to be the problem.

Comment: @user1911731: If your problem is solved, please post an answer describing what was exactly the issue and how you resolved it (maybe in a few more words than in your comment) so that this question is marked as "answered" and other people can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's removing extra spaces  which you can't see from your diff.

You can turn off this behaviour on Sublime with the setting `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save`, setting it to `false`